# jQuery モーダルを自動で消えるようにした後、再度ボタンをクリックできるようにする方法

Tags: jquery

3秒たったらモーダルが自動で消えるように設定したのですが、
自動で消えた後`$(modal).removeClass('SlideIn');$('body').removeClass('lock');`
をして、再度削除ボタンを押せるようにしたいのですが、
`removeClass`にならず、削除ボタンをクリックすることができません。

下記の2つを試してみたのですが、うまくいきませんでした。。

```
 var modalFadeout = $('.ModalOpen').click(function(){
  　$(modal).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
 });
 modalFadeout.done(function() {
   $(modal).removeClass('SlideIn');
   $('body').removeClass('lock');
 });
```

```
 $('.ModalOpen').click(function(){
    if($(modal).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow')){
      $(modal).removeClass('SlideIn');
      $('body').removeClass('lock');
    }
 });
```

jQueryの理解も低く、不足した情報があるかもしれませんが、
ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

```js
jQuery(function(){
  var modal;
  $('.ModalOpen').click(function(){
    $('body').addClass('lock');
    modal = '#' + $(this).attr('data-target');
    $(modal).addClass('SlideIn');
  });

  $('.ModalClose').off().click(function(){
    if (!modal) return;
    $(modal).removeClass('SlideIn');
    $('body').removeClass('lock');
  });

  $('.ModalOpen').click(function(){
   $(modal).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-content-drawer {
  background-color: #f7f4f4;
  opacity: 0.95;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 120px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -120px;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: auto;
  display: block;
  left: 10%;
  transition: ease .6s;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgb(156, 156, 156);
}
.lock{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.SlideIn {
  display: block;
  top: 70px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal-content-drawer {
    top: -170px;
  }
  .SlideIn {
    top: 140px;
  }
}
.modal-header-drawer {
  padding: 15px 0 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bebdbdde;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-header-drawer i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 15px;
}
.modal-body-drawer {
  padding: 15px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="ModalOpen btn btn-remove btn-sm pull-right" data-target="modal-content-01">削除</button>
 
<div id="modal-content-01" class="modal-content-drawer">
  <div class="modal-header-drawer">
    <button type="button" class="ModalClose btn btn-sm pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i>
    </button>
    <h5>削除</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body-drawer">
    <p>削除しました</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bodyにlockクラスを追加しているのは何をしようとしているのでしょうか？質問では削除ボタンを押せなくしているようですが、実際のコードを見ると押せなくしているわけではなく、スタイルを当てているだけで削除ボタンのクリックはできているようです。

Comment: ご指摘いただきましたlockクラスについて、body部分を非表示にしようと思っていましたが、今回の「削除ボタンが押せない」とは全く無関係のようでした。ただ、`$('.ModalOpen').click(function(){
   $(modal).delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
  });　`　を追加したことで、モーダルが自動で消えた後、再度削除ボタンを押してもボタンが反応せず、モーダルがでない状態となっています。removeClassするのではなく、他の処理をしなくてはいけないのでしょうか。。